# How does dpkg -L package_name works?

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, dpkg

I am curious about how exactly **dpkg -L** *package_name* works.

Here is what man says:

```
         -L, --listfiles package-name...
              List files installed to your system from package-name.
```

Here is the output of a `dpkg -L bash` executed as root :

```
/.
/usr
/usr/share
/usr/share/info
/usr/share/menu
/usr/share/menu/bash
/usr/share/lintian
/usr/share/lintian/overrides
/usr/share/lintian/overrides/bash
/usr/share/man
/usr/share/man/man7
/usr/share/man/man7/bash-builtins.7.gz
/usr/share/man/man1
/usr/share/man/man1/bash.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/rbash.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/clear_console.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/bashbug.1.gz
/usr/share/doc
/usr/share/doc/bash
/usr/share/doc/bash/RBASH
/usr/share/doc/bash/changelog.Debian.gz
/usr/share/doc/bash/copyright
/usr/share/doc/bash/README.abs-guide
/usr/share/doc/bash/POSIX.gz
/usr/share/doc/bash/inputrc.arrows
/usr/share/doc/bash/INTRO.gz
/usr/share/doc/bash/README.Debian.gz
/usr/share/doc/bash/NEWS.gz
/usr/share/doc/bash/COMPAT.gz
/usr/share/doc/bash/README.commands.gz
/usr/share/doc/bash/README
/usr/bin
/usr/bin/clear_console
/usr/bin/bashbug
/etc
/etc/skel
/etc/skel/.bashrc
/etc/skel/.bash_logout
/etc/skel/.profile
/etc/bash.bashrc
/bin
/bin/bash
/bin/rbash
```

How does dpkg know that ? Why isn’t (for example) */root/.bashrc* included ?

Comment: Why would it include `/root/.bashrc`? That is not a file in the package. That is a file that the user (optionally) creates manually. Anyway, this is not a programming question as required for Stackoverflow and hence is off-topic. Review the [help/on-topic] for what topics can be asked here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The contents of installed Debian packages are stored in plain text files at `/var/lib/dpkg/info/PACKAGENAME.list`.

For instance:

```
sh# cat /var/lib/dpkg/info/bash.list
/.
/etc
/etc/bash.bashrc
/etc/skel
/etc/skel/.profile
/etc/skel/.bash_logout
/etc/skel/.bashrc
/bin
/bin/bash
/usr
…
```

`/root/.bashrc` is not included because it is not a part of the `bash` package. It is copied from `/etc/skel/.bashrc` when the user is created, but is not overwritten if the `bash` package is updated, nor is it deleted if the package is uninstalled.

Comment: So bash uses and modify it, and it is a basic feature, but it isn't part of the bash package even thought it is programmed to  use it  ?
How is that bash.list generated in the first place ?

Comment: All of the files in `/var/lib/dpkg/info` are managed by `dpkg` when it installs, updates, or removes packages. With regard to bashrc: Keep in mind that other users have `.bashrc` files too! root isn't special in this regard, and the package obviously can't include a bashrc for every user on the system.